# Can't get Sidebar to show on Archives page (Wordpress, Elementor Pro+GeneratePress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I am trying to make an Archive Template for Wordpress using Elementor Pro and GeneratePress theme.
My posts and pages show the Sidebar (using the Default template) like it should but when I create a template for Archives using Elementor, the Sidebar isn't showing both in the builder and live site.

I tried the Default template, Full width, playing with the Fonctions.php but nothing seems to make the Sidebar appear. I Know I can make a 2 colums Layout and put the Sidebar Widget using Elementor but I would like to avoid that.

With Sidebar:
https://pasteboard.co/IXxJQ7E.png

Sidebar not shown:
https://pasteboard.co/IXxK6uv.png

Answer (score 0):

doesn't best solution but works:
create a new page as custom archive **page** via any custom link (look like to archive link) and redirect your archive links to new archive page link (by 301 redirect)

/category/archive/ ⇒ /archive-page/

/archive/ ⇒ /archive-page/